# passing multiple values from one page to another using anchor tag

Tags: asp.net

I need to pass two ids from one page to another page.One id is coming from datatable whereas second is passing manually but I am getting error of setting of null object reference in second one.My code is like this.

```
<a href='details.aspx?id=" + DataT.Rows[i][0] + " & pageId={1}'>read more</a>
```

Please suggest me what is wrong in my code?
Thankyou

Comment: what you want to give on pageid

Comment: @Ajay:I just want to give value 1 to pageId manually.

Comment: remove {} from pageid querystring.

Comment: I tried it but getting same error.

Comment: Did you tried trimming the space next to &???

Comment: This code - is not actually a code, just a line on the space. Can you please write the correct code that you use ? What is that `DataT.Rows[i][0]` ? and where this `{1}` come from ? This must start from {0} ! not from 1, where is that data ? where is the string.format ?

Comment: <div class='readmore'><a href='details.aspx?pageId=1 & id=" + DataT.Rows[i][0] .ToString() +"'> I tried like this then id has passed but now in another page when I am getting that id from Request.QueryString["id"] it is coming null.

Comment: Are you writing all this logic in aspx?

Comment: yes.Is this wrong?I am very begineers in asp.net.

Comment: see i sent an example.Not exact code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I giving an example not an exact answer.Follow the below logic in your Code.

Step1:Add a label in aspx page(To show hyperlink);

step2:create a Hyperlink in .cs code.

step3:Add that hyperlink to label(Which You create first)

For Example:

I add a label like

```
 <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
```

In .cs file i write the code like this:

```
string s = "YourCode";
Label1.Text="<a href='details.aspx?id="+ s +"&pageId=1'>read more</a>";
```

In your code s=DataT.Rows[i][0].Text;

Then You will get your required output.I just give logic .Make it in your way.

**NOTE:**

In "href",no spaces accepted.Beware of that.you will check in page view source